# How to remove automatically bind <p> </p> tags in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am using the **p-editor input  in primeng theme**.
i have tried many times to removed the `<p></p>` tags in javascript.but not working,

i tried all javascript codes. but i didn't get the solution,how to **remove automatically bind the `<p></p>` tags** in angular.

Comment: And you can't use the editor's `getEditorValue()` method and strip the content of any unneeded tags? See docs for method - https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/jsdocs/classes/src_PrimeFaces.PrimeFaces.widget.TextEditor-1.html#getEditorValue

Comment: how to use getEditorValue() and get value?

Comment: You use `ViewChild` (see [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)) to access your editor instance. Then you can access its properties and methods programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the text by using the `innerText` property of `nativeElement`.

Taking the `ViewChild` hint from @Aldin_Bradaric's comment, created a working demo below:

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-editor-demo-tnm8pg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<h5>Default</h5>
<p-editor #editor [(ngModel)]="text" [style]="{'height':'320px'}" (ngModelChange)="cleanString()"></p-editor>

<!-- for demo purpose -->
<p></p>
<div>Written text:</div>
{{ cleanText }}
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {
  text: string = '';
  cleanText = '';

  @ViewChild('editor', {static: false}) editor: any;

  cleanString() {
    this.cleanText = this.editor.el.nativeElement.innerText;
  }
}
```